# Error BC30616: Variable 'DBConnect' hides a variable in an enclosing block

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

I've adjusted some code which was written for me.. It sends out emails to my website members. I have added a part which selects items for sale on the site and puts them in the email (Featured items). However, I'm getting this error:

> D:\domains\example.com\httpdocs\sendFeaturedEmail.aspx.vb(79): error
>   BC30616: Variable 'DBConnect' hides a variable in an enclosing block.

Can anyone please show me how the code should be changed to work? I'm a fairly new programmer.. I'm learning by changing code that was written for me. Many Thanks for any help at all.

```vb
Public Sub SelectEmailDetails()

    Dim DBConnect As New DBConn
    Dim conn As SqlConnection = DBConnect.Conn("DBConnectionString")
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = DBConnect.Command(conn, "SelectEmailDetails")

    conn.Open()
    Dim DR As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)

    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    While DR.Read
        'While DR.Read And counter < 1

        Dim txtSubject As TextBox = fmvEmail.FindControl("txtSubject")
        Dim txtEmailReminderText As TextBox = fmvEmail.FindControl("txtEmailReminderText")
        Dim mm As New MailMessage
        mm.To.Add(New MailAddress(DR("emailAddress").ToString))
        mm.From = New MailAddress("admin@example.com", "example.com")
        mm.IsBodyHtml = True
        mm.Subject = txtSubject.Text

        Dim bodyText As New StringBuilder
        bodyText.AppendLine("<html><head><style>body { font-family:tahoma; font-size:1.0em; }</style></head><body>")
        bodyText.AppendLine("<p><a href='http://example.com'><img src='http://example.com/files/images/emailLogo.png' border='0' /></a></p>")


        bodyText.AppendLine("<p>Hurry.. Find these and more bargains in our current sale before they're gone..</p>")

        Dim DBConnect As New DBConn
        Using db As DbConnection = DBConnect.Conn("DBConnectionString")
            Dim cmd As SqlCommand = DBConnect.Command(db, "FeaturedEmail")

            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("MyDate", SqlDbType.Date, ParameterDirection.Input)).Value = MySale.prevDOW(DayOfWeek.Sunday).ToString("d")

            db.Open()
            Dim DR As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
            ltlItems.Text = ltlItems.Text & "<div style='width:90%; word-wrap: break-word;  margin:0 auto;'>"
            While DR.Read
                Dim friendlyOrderID = DR("link")
                Dim strText = "http://www.example.com/catalog/images/thumbnails/" & DR("strText")
                bodyText.AppendLine("<a href='" & friendlyOrderID & "'><img src='" & strText & "' /></a>")

            End While

            cmd.Dispose()
            cmd = Nothing
            db.Dispose()
            db.Close()
        End Using

        bodyText.AppendLine("</body></html>")
        mm.Body = bodyText.ToString

        Dim smtp As New SmtpClient
        smtp.Send(mm)

        counter = counter + 1
    End While

    cmd.Dispose()
    cmd = Nothing
    conn.Close()
    conn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: You've declared two variables named `DBConnect`.  Try declaring just one.

Comment: Thanks. I tried removing the 2nd Dim DBConnect As New DBConn and its gave me the same error in reference to 'cmd' so I removed the 2nd         Using db As DbConnection = DBConnect.Conn("DBConnectionString") and now I get D:\domains\onlinecarbooty.com\httpdocs\sendFeaturedEmail.aspx.vb(63): error BC32000: Local variable 'DR' cannot be referred to before it is declared.

Comment: Sorry, that may not have made sense.. I took the first 2nd Dim DBConnect As New DBConn but then it says the same about 'cmd'. I need it to access SQL stored procedure 'FeaturedEmail' so I need that line in but it tells me D:\domains\onlinecarbooty.com\httpdocs\sendFeaturedEmail.aspx.vb(80): error BC30616: Variable 'cmd' hides a variable in an enclosing block.

Comment: Clearly you've made a complete hash of that code.  I suggest that you start again.  When you need a variable, you declare it and then don't declare another one with the same name.

Comment: I renamed the variables for where it connects to the 'Featured Email' stored procedure and it works now :-) Sorry.. I just wasn't thinking, but you did help point me in the right direction.